# terraform state refresh and accept the changes and not change again with old code

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I have a huge terraform module setup to launch a entire infrastructure. Now post provisioning there were many changes applied to the setup manually. I updated the statefile to be aware of these changes using terraform refresh command.

Now I've added new components to my terraform. When I execute terraform plan it is trying to reset the old updated resources to it's initial state (coz that is what is defined in my terraform code). Is there any way for terraform to ignore the changes in the old resources and create only the newly added components?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself for the above. Apparently there is an option called ignore_changes under the lifecycle block that should be defined for all the resources that you expect to be changed using external methods.

Reference Link: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#ignore_changes